# Service Control Manager shows NA on User (Event Viewer)

Tags: windows-server-2012

How do I fix or make it so that the Service Control Manager would log the name of the user that stops or starts a service on Windows Server 2012 R2?

Right now whenever a service is started or stopped, it would log it on the Event Viewer under system, but would come up N/A on User.

Do you have any ideas?

[image: Event viewer]